# UDF function doesn't show the result

Tags: excel, vba, function, user-defined-functions

Hi guys is this possible ?

what's wring with that function. The z variable doesn't show the result.

```
Function Translate_H() As String
Worksheets("Dictionary").Activate
Dim O As Integer
Dim z As String
Dim Position_V2 As String
For O = 14 To 16
Position_V2 = Worksheets("Home").Cells(O + 1, 6).Address
Next O
Worksheets("Dictionary").Activate
z = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Position_V2, Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("$A$48:$AL$50"), 3, 0)

'Application.Volatile
'WorksheetFunction.Match(2, Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("$B$1:$AL$1"), 0) + 1, 0)

Translate_H = z
Application.Volatile
End Function
```

Comment: Why the FOR Loop? What objective does that serve?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout hi there. Because I need a general function related to the lookup value. I want use this Translate_H function as part of a formula bar function as a dynamic - general function. So it must give different result if i use in F15,F16,F17 cells. There is a list where i lookup those. but there is another sheet where i want use this.

Comment: Do you mean you want `=Translate_H()` in cell `F15` to give a different result to `=Translate_H()` in cell `F16`. Does the range `A48:A50` on dictionary sheet contain the strings `$F$15`,`$F$16`,`$F$17` ?

Comment: What I mean is that the FOR loop is useless becacuse the value of `Position_V2` will always be  picked up from `Worksheets("Home").Cells(16 + 1, 6).Address`. The previous values will be overwritten...

Comment: @CDP1802 yes. On dictionary sheet there is a list,, with the addresses from the home shee in the column 'A' +words. I would use 1 general functionin 3 cell on the home sheet. In F15, F16, F17. in that case the vba part would looking in the dictionary sheet the F15 lookup value and give some result. In position F16 it would looking for the F16 values. That's the plan, but other solutions also welcome.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout no because there would be 3 translate_ h function in 3 different position on the home page. In the first it would looking for F15, in second The F16 in the third the F17. But i need 1 function just for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter to your function. Then use as `=Translate_H(ROW())` in `F15:F17`.

```vb
Function Translate_H(r As Long) As String
    
    Dim Position_V2 As String, rngLookUp As Range
    Set rngLookUp = Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("A48:AL50")
    Position_V2 = Worksheets("Home").Range("F" & r).Address
    
    Translate_H = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Position_V2, rngLookUp, 3, 0)
    Application.Volatile

End Function
```

Comment: #CDP1802 thx but it doesn't show me any result. What is r in your code, how it's defined ?

Comment: @Zsolt what formula have you used in F15:F17

Comment: dear is used every combination of translate_H.   Like : Tranlste_H(),  translate(row()), translate(row(F15)).  I think I will use a technical row and use a simple lookup. Seems to me it's not possible what i want or nobody understand the real question. (I have 2 sheet ) Sheet 1 name :"Dictionary", sheet 2: "Home" I need the tranlsate_H function on "home" sheet to grab me data from "dictionary" but on home i want use the same function in cell F15 - F16, F17 without changing the lookup value.

Comment: @Zsolt Create a test sub and single step through it `Sub test() 
 MsgBox Translate_H(15)  End Sub`

Comment: hey. Maybe i am wrong but the function works a little bit differently as the sub. I need something which work perfectly as function.

Comment: @Zolt The Sub is just to debug the Function. What was the result ?

Comment: hey I need something which show me just this : F15 and use as a lookup part of a vlookup. when the vlookup is in the F15 is this possible ?

Comment: @zolt You need to post screenshots of your 2 sheets because I don't understand the problem you are having.

Comment: @ CDP1802 yeah. I don't know how to do that, there is no such a button i can use.

Comment: @Zolt there is an icon on the [editor toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) or use Cntrl-G

Comment: thanks' but I can't find that on my account page.

Comment: @Zaid It's not on your account page, its above where you posted the code, a mountain symbol to the right of **{}**.